# trying multiple proxies with selenium throws error in try except block python

Tags: python, selenium, try-catch, except

I can't figure out why it keeps trying even when it connects fine.

it seems like even if it catches an exception
even if i remove the catch all exception
once it has loaded the page successfully
it decides to keep looping.
it seems like it keeps trying.
python 3.8

def Load_Page(self,chrome):
chrome = chrome

```
try:
    whats_ip = 'https://www.whatsmyip.org/'
    chrome.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    print('Trying to get whats ip page')
    chrome.get(whats_ip)

    print(chrome.session_id)
    return chrome


except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
    self.Pick_Proxy()
    chrome.close()
    #time.sleep(1)
    self.Launch(question='reloading')
except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException as e:
    print(e)
    self.Pick_Proxy()
    chrome.close()
    #time.sleep(1)
    self.Launch(question='reloading')
except:
    print(Exception)
    self.Pick_Proxy()
    chrome.close()
    #time.sleep(1)
    self.Launch(question='reloading')
```

Comment: i tried to add the other parts of the code...

Comment: its like
def Launch(self,question):
    Load_proxy()
    chrome = open_Browser()
    chrome = THIS_FUNCTION(chrome) )FUNCTION IN QUSTION
    Load_Next_Page(chrome)